# RxJava `Completable.andThen` is not executing serially?

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a usecase where I initiallize some global variables in a Completable , and in the next step in the chain (using `andThen` operator) I make use of those variables.

Following sample explains my usecase in detail

Say you have a class `User`

```
        class User {
            String name;
        }
```

and I have an Observable like this ,

```
        private User mUser; // this is a global variable

        public Observable<String> stringObservable() {
            return Completable.fromAction(() -> {
                mUser = new User();
                mUser.name = "Name";
            }).andThen(Observable.just(mUser.name));
        }
```

First I'm doing some initiallizations in  my `Completable.fromAction` and I expect `andThen` operator to start only after completing the `Completable.fromAction`.

Which means I expect `mUser` to be initallized when the `andThen` operator starts.

Following is my subscription to this observable

```
             stringObservable()
            .subscribe(s -> Log.d(TAG, "success: " + s),
                    throwable -> Log.e(TAG, "error: " + throwable.getMessage()));
```

But when I run this code , I get an error

```
          Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String User.name' on a null object reference
```

which means `mUser` is null ,  `andThen` started before executing the code in  `Completable.fromAction`. Whats happening here?

According to documentation of `andThen`

> **Returns an Observable which will subscribe to this Completable and once that is completed then  will subscribe to the {@code next} ObservableSource. An error event from this Completable will be  propagated to the downstream subscriber and will result in skipping the subscription of the Observable.**

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The issue is not with `andThen` but with the statement  `Observable.just(mUser.name)` inside `andThen` . The `just` operator will try to create the observable immediately though it will emit only after `Completable.fromAction`.

Problem here is , while trying to create the `Observable` using just , the `mUser` is null.

**Solution** :  You need to defer the creation of the String Observable till a subscription happens , till the upstream of `andThen` starts emission.

Instead of `andThen(Observable.just(mUser.name));`

use

```
 andThen(Observable.defer(() -> Observable.just(mUser.name)));
```

Or

```
 andThen(Observable.fromCallable(() -> mUser.name));
```

Comment: `Observable.just(T)` docs states: "Note that the item is taken and **re-emitted as is** and not computed by any means by just. Use `fromCallable(Callable)` to **generate a single item** on demand (when Observers _subscribe to it_)."

Comment: Yes. the same is mentioned in the answer

Comment: Quoting the docs directly in the answer is a nice one to have, however

Answer (score 8):

I don't think @Sarath Kn's answer is 100% correct. Yes `just` will create observable as soon as it's called, but `andThen` is still calling `just` at an unexpected time.

We can compare `andThen` with `flatMap` to get some better understanding. Here is a fully runnable test:

```
package com.example;

import org.junit.Test;

import io.reactivex.Completable;
import io.reactivex.Observable;
import io.reactivex.observers.TestObserver;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;

public class ExampleTest {

    @Test
    public void createsIntermediateObservable_AfterSubscribing() {
        Observable<String> coldObservable = getObservableSource()
                .flatMap(integer -> getIntermediateObservable())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.trampoline())
                .observeOn(Schedulers.trampoline());
        System.out.println("Cold obs created... subscribing");
        TestObserver<String> testObserver = coldObservable.test();
        testObserver.awaitTerminalEvent();

        /*
        Resulting logs:

        Creating observable source
        Cold obs created... subscribing
        Emitting 1,2,3
        Creating intermediate observable
        Creating intermediate observable
        Creating intermediate observable
        Emitting complete notification

        IMPORTANT: see that intermediate observables are created AFTER subscribing
         */
    }

    @Test
    public void createsIntermediateObservable_BeforeSubscribing() {
        Observable<String> coldObservable = getCompletableSource()
                .andThen(getIntermediateObservable())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.trampoline())
                .observeOn(Schedulers.trampoline());
        System.out.println("Cold obs created... subscribing");
        TestObserver<String> testObserver = coldObservable.test();
        testObserver.awaitTerminalEvent();

        /*
        Resulting logs:

        Creating completable source
        Creating intermediate observable
        Cold obs created... subscribing
        Emitting complete notification

        IMPORTANT: see that intermediate observable is created BEFORE subscribing =(
         */
    }

    private Observable<Integer> getObservableSource() {
        System.out.println("Creating observable source");
        return Observable.create(emitter -> {
            System.out.println("Emitting 1,2,3");
            emitter.onNext(1);
            emitter.onNext(2);
            emitter.onNext(3);
            System.out.println("Emitting complete notification");
            emitter.onComplete();
        });
    }

    private Observable<String> getIntermediateObservable() {
        System.out.println("Creating intermediate observable");
        return Observable.just("A");
    }

    private Completable getCompletableSource() {
        System.out.println("Creating completable source");
        return Completable.create(emitter -> {
            System.out.println("Emitting complete notification");
            emitter.onComplete();
        });
    }
}
```

You can see that when we use `flatmap`, the `just` is called *after* subscribing, which makes sense. If the intermediate observable depended on the items emitted *to* the `flatmap` then of course the system can't create the intermediate observable before subscription. It would not yet have any values. You can imagine this wouldn't work if `flatmap` called `just` before subscribing:

```
.flatMap(integer -> getIntermediateObservable(integer))
```

What is weird is that `andThen` is able to create it's inner observable (i.e. call `just`) before subscribing. It makes sense that it *can* do this. The only thing `andThen` is going to receive is a complete notification, so there is no reason NOT to create the intermediate observable early. The only problem is that it's not the *expected* behavior.

@Sarath Kn's solution is correct, but for the wrong reason. If we use `defer` we can see things working as expected:

```
@Test
public void usingDefer_CreatesIntermediateObservable_AfterSubscribing() {
    Observable<String> coldObservable = getCompletableSource()
            .andThen(Observable.defer(this::getIntermediateObservable))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.trampoline())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.trampoline());
    System.out.println("Cold obs created... subscribing");
    TestObserver<String> testObserver = coldObservable.test();
    testObserver.awaitTerminalEvent();

    /*
    Resulting logs:

    Creating completable source
    Cold obs created... subscribing
    Emitting complete notification
    Creating intermediate observable

    IMPORTANT: see that intermediate observable is created AFTER subscribing =) YEAY!!
     */
}
```

Comment: I think this answer is correct but quite long. All we need to know is `andThen` takes a completable and returns it (or takes a single and returns that). If you do `func1(func2())`, func2 will not be called in func1's scope, it will be called the callers scope. Sarah is wrong to relate this to `.just`.